# Finding the sum of the infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Hi I am trying to solve the sum of the series of this problem:

$$
11 + 2 + \frac 4 {11} + \frac 8 {121} + \cdots
$$

I know its a geometric series, but I cannot find the pattern around this.

Comment: Hint : If you know that this is a geometric series, try calculating $\dfrac{u_{n+1}}{u_n}$

Comment: $a_n=\frac{2^n}{11^{n-1}}, s_n=11+\sum \frac{2^n}{11^{n-1}}=11+11\sum (\frac{2}{11})^n$

Comment: How do you know it's a geometric series if you can't find the pattern? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: It's a geometric series of ratio ${2\over 11}$ and a = 11

Answer (score 1):

- If your series  is

$$
S_1=11+11\times\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^n}{11^{n}}
$$
then you may use

> $$
> x+x^2+\cdots+x^n+\cdots=\frac{x}{1-x}, \quad |x|<1, \tag1
> $$

with $x=\dfrac2{11}$.

- If your series  is

$$
S_2=11+2+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{4n}{11^{n}}
$$
then differentiating $(1)$ termwise and multiplying by $x$ you get

> $$
> x+2x^2+3x^3+\cdots+nx^n+\cdots=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}, \quad |x|<1, \tag2
> $$

giving, with $x=\dfrac1{11}$,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{11^{n}}=\frac{11}{100}
$$

It is now pretty easy to obtain $S_2$.

Comment: Your indices are off in the first bullet...should be $\frac{2^n}{11^{n-1}}$

Comment: @gariepy Edited. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Q:** What does it mean to say a series is geometric?

**A:** It means there is a common ratio.
${}\qquad{}$I.e. the number by which you multiply each term to get the next is the **same** in every case.

What do you multiply $11$ by to get $2$?  You multiply it by $\dfrac 2 {11}$.

What do you multiply **that** by to get $\dfrac 4 {11}$?  You multiply it by $\dfrac 2 {11}$.

What do you multiply **that** by to get $\dfrac 8 {121}$?  You multiply it by $\dfrac 2 {11}$.

The fact that the thing by which you multiply is always the **same** thing is what the word "common" means.

The common ratio is $r=\dfrac 2 {11}$.

Remember that the sum of a geometric series is $\dfrac a {1-r}$, where $a$ is the first term (provided the common ratio is between $\pm1$).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

The geometric sequence can be rewritten as $\frac{1}{11^{-1}}, \frac{2}{11^0}, \frac{4}{11^1}, \frac{8}{11^2}...$
Notice the powers of two on top and powers of eleven on bottom

Answer (score 0):

Your series is a geometric series with a common ration of $q =\dfrac{2}{11}$ and a first term $a_0$ equal to $11$.
$-1 < \dfrac{2}{11}< 1$ so the series is convergent.
Its sum is equal to
$$a_0 \cdot \dfrac{1}{1-q} = 11 \cdot \dfrac{1}{1-\dfrac{2}{11}} = \dfrac{121}{9}$$